# In MKMapview how to get the list of driving direction in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview

In Map-view i got the route from source to destination properly. But i want to get list of route direction in map-view.I added below one sample link,likewise i need. Is it possible in iphone?if yes please help me how.
http://thumblines.com/2012/02/05/driving-directions-in-native-ios-and-android-apps/
now i am using the below code but its not working.

```
NSString *googleMapsURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&daddr=%1.6f,%1.6f", start.latitude, start.longitude, end.latitude, end.longitude];
```

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:googleMapsURLString]];

Comment: this has nothing to do with mapkit.

Answer (score 1):

Using Google Direction API , direction between two places could easily be found . It gives the response in the form of json/xml as per the user requirement . Here is a sample API used to find out the direction between two places .

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&sensor=false

Now by simply parsing the json obtained as response of the following API , direction instructions could easily be fetched . You can check the portability of this API by replacing the text for different Places . Hope it will help you .

Comment: Thanks for your rply.how i fetch the direction instruction only from the API Response.